# Maui Mopups System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, popup, maui

I'm new to MAUI development and still have a lot to learn but now stuck with Mopups. I migrated from Rg.Plugins.Popups and trying to use Mopups like this:

MyViewModel.cs

```
MopupService.Instance.PushAsync(new OrganizationPopup(this));
```

This is the OrganizationPopup class:

```
public partial class OrganizationPopup : PopupPage {
        
        private MyViewModel _viewModel;
        public OrganizationCodePopup(MyViewModel viewModel) {
            BindingContext = _viewModel = viewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Configured in MauiProgram.cs:

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp() {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
                .ConfigureMopups()
```

gettings this exception:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.CreateTypeWithInjection(Type viewType, IMauiContext mauiContext) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 47
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 85
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Layout\LayoutHandler.Android.cs:line 43
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 69
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 19
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:line 305
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Layout\LayoutHandler.Android.cs:line 43
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 69
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 19
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:line 305
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.UpdateContent() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Android\FrameRenderer.cs:line 366
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.<>c.<.cctor>b__67_6(FrameRenderer h, Frame _) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Android\FrameRenderer.cs:line 32
2023-09-12 01:33:29.023 17618-17618 mono-rt                 com.mycompany.myproject A     at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 172
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 47
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 82
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.VisualElementRenderer`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view, IPlatformViewHandler nativeViewHandler, Action`1 onElementChanged, Frame& currentVirtualView, IPropertyMapper& _mapper, IPropertyMapper _defaultMapper, Boolean autoPackage) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\VisualElementRenderer.cs:line 280
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ViewHandlerDelegator`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view, Action`1 onElementChanged, Boolean autoPackage) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\ViewHandlerDelegator.cs:line 86
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.Microsoft.Maui.IElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Android\FrameRenderer.cs:line 397
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 69
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 19
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:line 305
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 44
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 49
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 172
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 47
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 82
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 79
2023-09-12 01:33:29.023 17618-17618 mono-rt                 com.mycompany.myproject                  A     at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement element) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandler.cs:line 134
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 53
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 27
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 69
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 19
                                                                                                       at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.set_Handler(IViewHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:line 35
                                                                                                       at Mopups.Interfaces.IPopupPlatform.GetOrCreateHandler[PopupPageHandler](VisualElement bindable)
                                                                                                       at Mopups.Droid.Implementation.AndroidMopups.AddAsync(PopupPage page)
                                                                                                       at Mopups.Services.PopupNavigation.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<PushAsync>g__PushPage|0>d.MoveNext()
                                                                                                    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Is it something related to Dependency Injection? Because i only registered Services

Comment: the stacktrace says line 47 of your ElementExtensions.cs

Comment: Also what I don't quite understand is that the name of the constructor for `OrganizationPopup` is `OrganizationCodePopup` instead of `OrganizationPopup`?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT sorry about that, my mistake. It should be OrganizationPopup

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that i was using CustomRenderers. Turns out i can't use it with Mopups